# Django, storing HTML code in databases

Tags: python, django, database-design, web

So I am currently designing a website that I am deploying on Heroku with Django.

I want to have project pages that I load dynamically using templates (instead of hard coding various HTML templates) and loading them dynamically into a div on page load time. These pages are going to be "project" pages and I am currently thinking of the best way to store them.

I do not think they will be overly similar to each other since I want different pages to use different HTML, though the general layout will be similar. I also want to be able to store code sections, much like stack overflow.

I have 2 ideas on how to store the information:

1) Create a text field and let myself render the HTML tags (since its only me the admin posting to these pages)

2) Create HTML templates and use a database to store links to the pages so I can dynamically render a side tab to view the latest and easily archive them.

What would be the best approach? Any other ideas are welcome as well.

Comment: I think you are lookinf for https://github.com/divio/django-cms

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to use include tag in your template with some logic.

```
    {% if something %}
         {% include "custom_pages/bar.html" %}
    {% else %}
         {% include "custom_pages/foo.html" %}
    {% endif %}
```

and you can always edit your html files easy.